# How do I launch a completely independent process from a Java program?

Tags: java, exec, external-process

I am working on a program written in Java which, *for some actions*, launches external programs using user-configured command lines.  Currently it uses `Runtime.exec()` and does not retain the `Process` reference (the launched programs are either a text editor or archive utility, so no need for the system in/out/err streams).

There is a minor problem with this though, in that when the Java program exits, it doesn't really quit until all the launched programs are exited.

I would greatly prefer it if the launched programs were completely independent of the JVM which launched them.

The target operating system is multiple, with Windows, Linux and Mac being the minimum, but any GUI system with a JVM is really what is desired (hence the user configurability of the actual command lines).

Does anyone know how to make the launched program execute completely independently of the JVM?

---

**Edit in response to a comment**

The launch code is as follows.  The code may launch an editor positioned at a specific line and column, or it may launch an archive viewer.  Quoted values in the configured command line are treated as ECMA-262 encoded, and are decoded and the quotes stripped to form the desired exec parameter.

The launch occurs on the EDT.

```
static Throwable launch(String cmd, File fil, int lin, int col) throws Throwable {
    String frs[][]={
        { "$FILE$"  ,fil.getAbsolutePath().replace('\\','/') },
        { "$LINE$"  ,(lin>0 ? Integer.toString(lin) : "") },
        { "$COLUMN$",(col>0 ? Integer.toString(col) : "") },
        };
    String[] arr; // array of parsed tokens (exec(cmd) does not handle quoted values)

    cmd=TextUtil.replace(cmd,frs,true,"$$","$");
    arr=(String[])ArrayUtil.removeNulls(TextUtil.stringComponents(cmd,' ',-1,true,true,true));
    for(int xa=0; xa<arr.length; xa++) {
        if(TextUtil.isQuoted(arr[xa],true)) {
            arr[xa]=TextDecode.ecma262(TextUtil.stripQuotes(arr[xa]));
            }
        }
    log.println("Launching: "+cmd);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arr);
    return null;
    }
```

---

This appears to be happening only when the program is launched from my IDE.  I am closing this question since the problem exists only in my development environment; **it is not a problem in production**.  From the test program in one of the answers, and further testing I have conducted I am satisfied that it is not a problem that will be seen by any user of the program on any platform.

Comment: I think you mean you're currently using Runtime.exec()

Comment: I suspect this is only a Windows problem. Certainly on the Mac, I've had the opposite problem: making sure the external process I launched _does_ exit when the JVM exits.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It may help if you post a test section of minimal code needed to reproduce the problem.  I tested the following code on Windows and a Linux system.

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args[0]);
    }
}
```

And tested with the following on Linux:

```
java -jar JustForTesting.jar /home/monceaux/Desktop/__TMP/test.sh
```

where test.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -i 20 localhost
```

as well as this on Linux:

```
java -jar JustForTesting.jar gedit
```

And tested this on Windows:

```
java -jar JustForTesting.jar notepad.exe
```

All of these launched their intended programs, but the Java application had no problems exiting.  I have the following versions of Sun's JVM as reported by `java -version` :

- Windows:  1.6.0_13-b03
- Linux:    1.6.0_10-b33

I have not had a chance to test on my Mac yet.  Perhaps there is some interaction occuring with other code in your project that may not be clear.  You may want to try this test app and see what the results are.

Comment: This problem might be limited to Windows XP, or it might only be a result of the way the JVM is launched from my IDE during testing.  On Windows Vista, it is not happening for the distributed build.  After testing on XP, this answer will be accepted if it shows a problem also only when the JVM is launched from the IDE.

Comment: This appears only to be happening when launched from my IDE, so I am accepting this answer as indicating that my problem exists only in my development environment; it is not a problem in production.

Comment: Monceaux: Thanks, BTW, this simple test was what made me look closer at the precise conditions under which the program didn't exit - from which I realized it was my *IDE* launcher and not Java which was not exiting.

Comment: I need to keep run the process after finishing main code, but the process by Runtime looks run only while main class thread is running and the process looks killed, when the main thread is terminated. So work around is spawning shell in the command like **cmd /c start my.bat** for windows and **xterm -e ./my.sh &** for linux. That keeps run after finishing the main.

Comment: Please add a note that this is dangerous though. If the program started by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args[0])` produces more output than the output buffer can hold, the application will freeze.

Answer (score 30):

There is a parent child relation between your processes and you have to break that.
For Windows you can try:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start editor.exe");
```

For Linux the process seem to run detached anyway, no nohup necessary.
I tried it with `gvim`, `midori` and `acroread`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class Exec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/acroread");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

I think it is not possible to to it with [Runtime.exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) in a platform independent way.

for POSIX-Compatible system:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "your command"}).waitFor();
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be something I could do in the process creation... this requires the user to configure the "correct" command line.  But good to know.

Comment: You can have the user configure the correct command line and 
and sneakily add the operating system specific magic when necessary.

Comment: `catch (IOException e)` does not replace neither `.waitFor()` nor `InterruptedException`

Comment: Thank you so much. My team has been investigating an issue with a component C++ software that we launch from java. It turns out to be a security issue imposed by the JVM process. This solved the issue. Thanks so much.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html gives additional information about how to pass in parameters to "cmd". http://ss64.com/nt/start.html is the same for "start".

Comment: I can confirm that on Linux the process is run completely detached. I run a bash one-liner that kills Tomcat itself and restarts it (only on development machines!) and killing Tomcat does not in any way stop the script.

Answer (score 25):

I have some observations that may help other people facing similar issue.

When you use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() and then you ignore the java.lang.Process handle you get back (like in the code from original poster), there is a chance that the launched process may hang.

I have faced this issue in Windows environment and traced the problem to the stdout and stderr streams. If the launched application is writing to these streams, and the buffer for these stream fills up then the launched application may appear to hang when it tries to write to the streams. The solutions are:

1. Capture the Process handle and empty out the streams continually - but if you want to terminate the java application right after launching the process then this is not a feasible solution
2. Execute the process call as `cmd /c <<process>>` (this is only for Windows environment).
3. Suffix the process command and redirect the stdout and stderr streams to nul using '*command > nul 2>&1*'

Comment: Thanks. Totally worked for me in case of launching kryonet clients. Option 1 can be implemented using inheritIO method of ProcessBuilder. It sends all the stream content to the parent Java process. So no need to make processes independent

Comment: I had a problem coding a custom luncher where the child processes (mostly chromium and pidgin) freeze after running for several hours, but as soon as the luncher exits, they unfreeze immediately. Googled and debugged now for a week, and this is the very best answer for my problem I've found. If this was also my problem I would give you 100 k points for that answer.

Comment: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html gives additional information about how to pass in parameters too.

Comment: YOU SAVED MEEE!!! I had two jars, one launching other. If the child processs hanged up, even after the parent process relaunched it, the child process still hung up. Only when I killed the parent process, the child process started to work again. Redirecting stdout to null with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd /c java -jar myjar.jar args > nul 2>&1") fixed it!!

Comment: Thanks Manavendra and @Gaurav, it helped me to fix a issue which I was looking for last 2 days

Answer (score 2):

You want to launch the program in the background, and separate it from the parent.  I'd consider [nohup(1)](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/801-6680-01/6i11qc0i8?l=en&a=view).

Comment: Well, for Linux, sure... But the problem isn't that the launched process is being terminated, it's that the JVM won't end until the launched program(s) is(are) also ended.

Comment: DId you actually *try* it?  A nohup'ed background process should appear to the system() call as if it immediately terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this would require a actual process fork.  Basically, the C equivalent of what you want is:

```
pid_t id = fork();
if(id == 0)
  system(command_line);
```

The problem is you can't do a fork() in pure Java.  What I would do is:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
      try
      {
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {           
          // Handle error.
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
});
t.start();
```

That way the JVM still won't exit, but no GUI and only a limited memory footprint will remain.

Comment: This is exactly the problem the O.P tries to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything mentioned here but without success. Main parent Java process can't quit until the quit of subthread even with cmd /c start and redirecting streams tu nul.

Only one reliable solution for me is this:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("psexec -i cmd /c start cmd.cmd");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // handle it
}
```

I know that this is not clear, but this small utility from SysInternals is very helpful and proven. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) is the link.

Answer (score -2):

One way I can think of is to use Runtime.addShutdownHook to register a thread that kills off all the processes (you'd need to retain the process objects somewhere of course).

The shutdown hook is only called when the JVM exits so it should work fine.

A little bit of a hack but effective.

Comment: Except I don't want to kill the processes.  What I want is for them to not prevent the JVM from exiting.  I think my users would be quite surprised at exiting my app and seeing several other programs disappear along with it.