# Java - how to launch and forget process

Tags: java, process

I'm trying to laumch some bat file on my computer,
I'm using the Process.exec to do it.
The problem is that the bat file start another process, and my program is waiting for it to complete, but I need my program to stop although the child process is keep running.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do, in this code I'm lauching the notepad and the program is stuck until I'm manualy close the notepd window - so what I'm should do for my program to end and notepad will keep running?

```
    public static Process test3 () throws IOException
   {
   Process p;
   try
      {
      p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "notepad" );
      }
   catch ( IOException e )
      {
      return null;
      }
      try
         {
         p.waitFor();
         }
      catch ( InterruptedException e )
         {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         }


   p.getInputStream().close();
   p.getOutputStream().close();
   p.getErrorStream().close();

   return p;
   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in Windows, try this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd /c start notepad" );
```

Comment: down-voter, leave comment next time! (what was wrong with that?)

Comment: @aviad : Too true, one must always tell the reason. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will help :

```
public class ExternalProcess
{
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Notepad");
        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getOutputStream().close();
        p.getErrorStream().close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Simply use System.exit(0);

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the ProcessBuilder class for more flexibility!!!