# preventing child JVM from exiting when its parent JVM exits

Tags: java, linux, process, jvm

I have a parent JVM (which I'll call **JVM_parent**) and inside it I launched another JVM using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java .......")` (which I'll call **JVM_child**)

Now when I shutdown (either gracefully or forcefully) **JVM_parent**, the **JVM_child** also exits.

How can I prevent the **JVM_child** from being shut down when the **JVM_parent** is shut down? I'm running on Linux.

Comment: You can try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program                            The issue is that you need to detach the child process from the parent and that procedure differs per operating system.

Comment: @sagneta +1 well yes detaching parent and child is the key. let me try.

Comment: not able to detach using bash -c or /bin/sh -c options.

Comment: Why not?  Every Linux system has the `bash` command!

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to create a bash script that executes your other process with a 'nohup &'. That is you want a line like:   nohup ./myprogram &

Comment: you might want to look into jnr-posix, it provides better access to libc APIs than the standard ProcessBuilder.

Comment: update: When I kill parent  by CTRL+C,  JVM_child is also killed. But when I kill JVM_parent by kill -9,  JVM_child survives. I know that CTRL+C raises a SIGINT and kill -9 raises a SIGKILL but anyhow SIGKILL is more brutal than SIGINT

Comment: Any reasons why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child process will inherit from the parent such that kill signals will also kill the child process. To prevent this you need to detach the child from the parent so it won't receive those signals and will continue on.

The easiest way to use this is running something like `bash nohup prog &` which runs it in a separate child and doesn't listen to the HUP signal. Note that running `bash -c` is not sufficient. You can tell using something like `pstree` whether the bash process has finished.