# Start another java program inside a java program and kill the mother process

Tags: java, ubuntu

I use terminal command "java -jar secondApp.jar" inside my java file to start a secondApp.jar. 
I need secondApp.jar to run even if first app is killed. 
This scenario works perfectly in windows environment. But when I test this in linux environment(Ubuntu 16.04) it seems that killing the first process kills the both processes.
This is the code I use to start the second app.

```
String command = "java -jar secondApp.jar"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "even if the first app is killed". if you terminate the JVM in which it runs, which is the way to "kill" the process, the second one will be terminated as well since, it runs in the same JVM

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931536/how-do-i-launch-a-completely-independent-process-from-a-java-program

Comment: how about `"java -jar secondApp.jar &"` for linux?

Comment: @Stultuske I'm not terminating JVM. I just kill the pid of the first app

Comment: @Arvind not working

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a batch file and a linux script file with the desired java command, then try this:

```
    if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
        // run batch file
        String batchFullPath = new File("C:\\myBatchFile.bat").getAbsolutePath();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start " + batchFullPath);
    } else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
        // run linux script
        String scriptFullPath = new File("~/myScriptFile.sh").getAbsolutePath();
        File workingDir = new File("~");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/xterm " + scriptFullPath, null, workingDir);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Operating System");
    }
```

(Using xterm as it is fairly safe to assume every Linux machine has it installed)